# Get vector from vector of vectors

Tags: r

When I have a vector of vectors in R, how do I select a vector that contains one element from each outer vector?

For example, given this data:

```
> data<-c("1,2","3,4","5,6")
> data<-strsplit(data,",")
> data
[[1]]
[1] "1" "2"

[[2]]
[1] "3" "4"

[[3]]
[1] "5" "6"
```

How do I get a vector containing (1,3,5) and nothing else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your example uses `strsplit` I assume this is how you obtain your dataset in the first place? If so, using regular expressions also work and might be slightly faster. e.g.

```
data <- c("1,2","3,4","5,6")

# Remove everything after ,:
gsub(",.*","",data)

# Select first number:
regmatches(data,regexpr("\\d+",data))
```

Comment: Yes, I had a CSV, but one of the columns is actually a list of two values separated by a comma. I had thought about regex, but ended up just writing a loop. This is useful, however, and the gsub approach works even though my real data has missing/NA values.

`data<-data <- c("1,2","3,4",NA,"5,6")
col1<-gsub(",.*","",data)
col2<-gsub(".*,","",data)`

Answer (score 8):

One way is to use [`sapply`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/lapply.html) :

```
> sapply( data, "[[", 1 )
[1] "1" "3" "5"
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return a numeric vector because read.table will apply its tests to the columns:

```
> read.table(text=data, sep=",")$V1
[1] 1 3 5
```

It is probably unwise to use the name 'data' for vectors since it is also the name of a base function.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
unlist(data)[c(TRUE, rep(FALSE, length(data[[1]]) - 1))]

[1] "1" "3" "5"
```

Comment: Even simpler would be: `unlist(data)[c(TRUE, FALSE)]`

Comment: @DWin I know that it's easy in this particular case, but my command also works if the vectors are longer than two elements.

Comment: Right, and neither one of our solutions work as expected when the splits are of unequal lengths.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following recursive function which will work even if your lists are more than 2-levels deep

```
getElemsR <- function(dat, Index, Lev=2)  {
  if ((Lev <- (Lev - 1)) > 1)  {
    inds <- seq(length(dat[[1]]))
    dat <- unlist(lapply(inds, function(i) getElemsR(dat, i, Lev)), recursive=F)
  } 
  sapply(dat, "[[", Index, USE.NAMES=T, simplify=F)
}

# get the 2nd element of every 2nd-Level list
getElemsR(myData, 3)  # Lev=2 by default

# get the 2nd element of every 3rd-Level list
getElemsR(myData, 2, 3)

# if needed as a vector:
unlist(getElemsR(myData, 2, 3))
```

---

Alternatively, if your lists are only two-levels deep, you can use a simply sapply as @Romain pointed out. 
You can wrap this in a function

```
getElems <- function (dat, Index)  {
  sapply(dat, "[[", Index)
}

# get the 2nd element of every 2nd-level list
getElems(data1, 2)
```

---

Sample Data

```
data1 <- lapply(1:3, paste0, c("A","B"))
data2 <- lapply(4:6, paste0, c("A","B"))
names(data1) <- names(data2) <- c("_sub1", "_sub2", "_sub3")
myData <- list(Lev1A=data1, Lev1B=data2)
```

Comment: Thanks, Ricardo. Any way to easily expand this to work if the data contains missing/NA values? e.g. if my sample data was as above, but then data[[2]]<-NA?

Comment: possibly...    does it specifically have a value of NA, or is it out of bounds?

Comment: Actually has a value of NA, which works fine for `sapply(dat,"[[",1)` but causes a subscript out of bounds error for `sapply(dat,"[[",2)` as the NA values have only one dimension.

Comment: Can you post a sample of or a link to your data?  Also, perhaps can you elaborate more on the goal?

Answer (score 0):

Or this :-) :

```
foo<- unlist(data)
matrix(foo,nrow=length(data),byrow=TRUE)[,1] 

[1] "1" "3" "5"
```